# How to find boundaries and setView of no geographical map~ Leaflet

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, maps, png

I try to find a way to insert random images at leaflet map and these images fit properly inside the map, *like object-fit: contain* .

```
let map = L.map('mapImage', {
        maxZoom: 1,
        minZoom: 1,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        doubleClickZoom: false,
    }).setView([0, 0], 1);

let bounds :any= [[0,0], [1000,1000]];
     L.imageOverlay(backGroundUrl, 
     bounds).addTo(this.map);
```

I tried to convert units to pixels for bounds but nothing worked for me. How to deal with setView() and bounds to  fit any image to map?
Thank you

Comment: This should be enough: `map.fitBounds(bounds);`
As for automatically downloading bounds, all you need to do is get with and height from img.